# How can I keep my mysql tables for the next time I boot up vagrant

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm using the homestead feature included with laravel and taking advantage of the built in mysql database. This is my first time using a VM and after doing some work with tables, the next time I run "vagrant up" all my data is gone.

Is this supposed to happen? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

vagrant up will start your VM and create it too if it is not already created.
The question is how are you stopping your VM. I am guessing you are using vagrant destroy(will remove your VM). You should use vagrant halt(**shutdown**).

[Basic vagrant operations(init, poweron, restart, poweroff, destroy, ssh)](http://www.brownfort.com/2014/09/init-poweron-restart-poweroff-destroy-ssh-vagrant-boxes/)

Comment: I've been using vagrant suspend

Comment: Actually now that I check, I have a whole bunch of VMs in my VirtualBox VMs folder. What could be causing this?